# What does OpenMP structured-block mean in fortran?

Tags: syntax, fortran, openmp

What does openMP structured-block mean in fortran?

Using the [sections construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu37.html) as an example:

```
!$omp sections
   !$omp section 
      structured-block 
   !$omp section 
      structured-block 
   ... 
!$omp end sections
```

Can I have multiple commands under each section like this?

```
!$omp sections
  !$omp section
    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
  !$omp section
    command 4
    command 5
    command 6
  ...
!$omp end sections
```

Is this a correct use of the sections construct and more specifically "structured-block"?

Comment: OpenMP defines "structured block" in its glossary.  Could you read that (if you haven't) and then refine the question based on any particular difficulty?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @francescalus. From the [glossary](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu2.html) it defines structured block as:
"For Fortran, a block of executable statements with a single entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom, or an OpenMP construct." 
I'm quite new to OpenMP and would like an example for clarity, please.

Comment: Examples: https://www.openmp.org//wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *"block of executable statements with a single entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom"* means that you do not use `goto` to transfer control to a label inside the block and do not use goto to transfer control to a label outside the block.

```
!$omp section
  call foo()
  bar = baz
  qux = bar
!$omp section
  ...
```

is fine if `foo()` returns.

```
!$omp section
  bar = foo()
  if (bar == baz) then
    goto qux
  end if
!$omp section
  ...

qux: ...
```

is not fine.

You can have a loop inside as long as its entire body is contained in the block and you can call functions and subroutines as long as they return.

Comment: Thank you. So multiple commands is fine within a section then?

Comment: Yes, that's why it is called a structured block _sequence_ in OpenMP 5.1.

Comment: https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu2.html#x9-80001.2.2 has the definitions if they help :-)

Comment: Thanks Jim Cownie. That was helpful